# swift 4.0 package generate-xcodeproj not work

Tags: swift, swift-package-manager

swift version: 4.0

Xcode version: 9.0

i want to create a swift command line tool. And i want to use [CommandLine](https://github.com/jatoben/CommandLine). 
This is my Package.swift:

```
import PackageDescription

let package = Package(
name: "Fengniao",
dependencies: [
    .package(url: "https://github.com/jatoben/CommandLine", from: "3.0.0-pre1")
],
targets: [
    .target(
        name: "Fengniao",
        dependencies: []),
]
)
```

and then i use the following swift command:

```
swift package resolve
swift build
swift package generate-xcodeproj
```

and then i open the .xcodeproj. But there's no `CommandLine` in my Targets list. There are two Targets instead: `FengniaoPackageDescription` and `Fengniao`. And `CommandLineKit` can not be imported into my `main.swift`。

which step is wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

None of your targets actually have a dependency on CommandLine. Change your target declaration to:

```
.target(
        name: "Fengniao",
        dependencies: ["CommandLine"])
```

And then this should work.

Comment: note: the dependencies string array is looking for the actual library name created from the git which may not be related to the git name.  (i.e., the string you use next to 'import' in the code)